# How to find Bragg reflexes fast with numpy?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scientific-computing

For x-ray diffraction one needs to find the solutions to the so called Laue-Equation

G_hkl - k_in + |k_in|*(sin(theta) cos(phi) , sin(theta) sin(phi) , cos(theta))=0

where G_hkl is a given 3 dimensional vector, k_in can be chosen as (0,0,1) and theta and phi are free parameters to fulfill the equation. In a typical experiment G_hkl is then rotated around the x-axis and for every step in the rotation one needs to find the solution to the equation. The equation cannot have more than one solution at a given rotation.

I have written this python script to find these solution but for my application it is not fast enough.

```
import numpy as np
import time
# Just initialization of variables. This is fast enough
res_list = []
N_rot = 100
Ghkl = np.array([0,0.7,0.7])
Ghkl_norm = np.linalg.norm(Ghkl)
kin = np.array([0,0,1])
kin_norm = np.linalg.norm(kin)
alpha_step = 2*np.pi/(N_rot-1)
rot_mat = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,np.cos(alpha_step),-np.sin(alpha_step)],[0,np.sin(alpha_step),np.cos(alpha_step)]])

# You can deduce theta from the norm of the vector equation
theta = np.arccos(1-(Ghkl_norm**2/(2*kin_norm**2))) 
sint = np.sin(theta)
cost = np.cos(theta)

# This leaves only phi as paramter to find
# I find phi by introducing a finite test vector
# and testing whether the norm of the vector equation is close
# to zero for any of those test phis
phi_test = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)

kout = kin_norm * np.array([sint * np.cos(phi_test), sint * np.sin(phi_test), cost + 0*phi_test]).T
##############
start_time = time.time()

for j in range(100): # just to make it longer to measure the time
    res_list = []
    for i in range(N_rot): # This loop is too slow
        # Here the norm of the vector equation is calculated for all phi_test
        norm_vec = np.linalg.norm(Ghkl[np.newaxis, :] - kin[np.newaxis, :] + kout, axis=1)
        if (norm_vec < 0.01 * kin_norm).any(): # check whether any fulfills the criterion
            minarg = np.argmin(norm_vec)
            res_list.append([theta, phi_test[minarg]])
        Ghkl = np.dot(rot_mat,Ghkl)

print('Time was {0:1.2f} s'.format( (time.time()-start_time)))
# On my machine it takes 0.3s and res_list should be 
# [[1.0356115365192968, 1.578689775673263]]
```

Do you know a faster way to calculate this, either conceptually by solving the equation totally different or by just making it faster with my existing method?

Comment: Where are you using the iterator `i`?

Comment: This controls the rotation. Ghkl  is always updated (rotated by one step) in the last line of the loop.

Comment: I mean I don't see the iterator `i` being used for calculations inside that loop : `for i in range(N_rot):` and as such we can push up those calculations outside of that loop.

Comment: i is not used inside the loop and you can replace it with _ but I don't think you can just pull out anything from that loop. Ghkl is update in every iteration of that loop and norm_vec and everything else depend on Ghkl

Comment: Ah I see now! There is dependency between iterations as we are updating `Ghkl` and that's being re-used in that loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a dependency as `Ghkl` is being updated at each iteration and re-used at the next. The corresponding closed form might be difficult to trace out. So, I would focus on improving the performance on the rest of the code inside that innermost loop.

Now, there we are calculating `norm_vec`, which I think could be sped up with two methods as listed next.

**Appproach #1** Using [`Scipy's cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

norm_vec = cdist(kout,(kin-Ghkl)[None]) # Rest of code stays the same
```

**Appproach #2** Using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
sums = (Ghkl-kin)+kout
norm_vec_sq = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',sums,sums)
if (norm_vec_sq < (0.01 * kin_norm)**2 ).any():
    minarg = np.argmin(norm_vec_sq) # Rest of code stays the same
```

Runtime test -

Using the inputs listed in the question, we have these results :

```
In [91]: %timeit np.linalg.norm(Ghkl- kin + kout, axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.1 µs per loop

In [92]: sums = (Ghkl-kin)+kout
    ...: norm_vec_sq = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',sums,sums)
    ...: 

In [93]: %timeit (Ghkl-kin)+kout                 # Approach2 - step1
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.09 µs per loop

In [94]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->i',sums,sums) # Approach2 - step2
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.82 µs per loop

In [95]: %timeit cdist(kout,(kin-Ghkl)[None])    # Approach1
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.1 µs per loop
```

So, approach #1 isn't showing any improvement for those input sizes, but approach #2 is getting around `3x` speedup there on calculating `norm_vec`.

**Short note on why `np.einsum` is beneficial here :**  Well, `einsum` is great for elementwise multiplication and sum-reduction. We are exploiting that very nature of problem here. `np.linalg.norm` gives us summations along the second axis on the squared version of the input. So, the `einsum` counterpart would be to just feed the same input twice as the two inputs to it, thus taking care of the squaring and then lose the second axis with its sum-reduction that is expressed with its string notation. It does both these in one go and that's probably why it's so fast here.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! Could you briefly explain to me why approach two is faster?

Comment: @Jannick Added a note at the end on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your answer. I will be using einsum much more in the future. I also thought about it and np.linalg.norm also needs to calculate a square root at some point, which is unnecessary in your solution. So this might add to the speed increase

Comment: @Jannick Ah yes! Forgot to mention the `sqrt` part too, that's another big improvement we get from `einsum`.

Answer (score 0):

The diffraction from any plane of atoms can be obtained by just taking the Fourier transform of the atomic positions. The Fourier space resolution is defined by your overall lattice size.

More details of the implementation can be found here: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-651X/ac860c

I'll update this answer with the repository that computes the XRD once I make it public.